# How to add a string at the end of line in python

Tags: python

concatenate the string at the end of line of the file.txt with condition

I have 2 inputs and one file.txt

file.txt have below lines

```
A1|books
A2|pen
A3|ball
```

input1,input2

- input1 has to select which line has to add  (A1,A2 or A3)
- input2 has to select what string has to added

input1=A1, input2=|pen|

then my expected file.txt is

```
A1|books|pen|
A2|pen
A3|ball
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(filename,a,b):
    txt1,txt2="",""
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        txt1 =f.readline().strip()
        while(txt1):
            if a==txt1[:len(a)]:
                txt1+=b
            txt2+=txt1+'\n'
            txt1=f.readline().strip()
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        f.write(txt2)

func("file.txt","A1","|pen")
```

Comment: while writing new line is adding, if i remove \n then its combining the two lines. can you verify once

Comment: Done. One more strip at line 9

Answer (score 0):

load the file as csv using '|' as delimiter and save as dictionary... first column as key and second column as value in a list.

the sctructure should be like:

```
dictionary = {column1 : [column2]}
```

That's basically the logic for your answer, do the rest yourself.